# How to create a library that targets both .NET 2.0 and .NET Standard?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-standard

I have a [small library](https://github.com/balazsbotond/FluentUriBuilder) that currently supports .NET 2.0+.

I don't use any features of the later framework versions so it would be nice to keep 2.0 support, but I also want to target .NET Core (or more precisely, .NET Standard).

I tried to add both frameworks to `project.json`:

```
"frameworks": {
  "net20": {},
  "netstandard1.6": {
    "imports": "dnxcore50"
  }
}
```

But the NuGet packages my library needs to run on .NET Standard (`System.Reflection` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities`) aren't compatible with .NET 2.0.

How can I solve this issue without maintaining two completely separate projects with almost identical code?

Comment: The question is what for do you need .NET Framework 2.0 support, if you want to use an package which has a minimum requirement of 4.5.1 / netstandard 1.3 (=.NET Framework 4.6)? Do you want to use it with legacy ASP.NET 4? If not, there is no reason to target that low if has an dependency on ASP.NET Core, as ASP.NET Core won't run on anything lower than 4.5 or 4.5.1

Answer (score 5):

You can't, if you depend on `Microsoft.AspNetCore.*` packages as the **absolute** minimum for supporting .NET Standard is .NET 4.5.

.NET 4.5 is the first version to include `System.Runtime` on which .NET Core is based on. But when you think closer about it, it also makes no sense. If you need support for ASP.NET Core within your library.

If your library is supposed to run for ASP.NET Core and ASP.NET 4 (i.e. MVC 5, WebApi 2), then you will need to use your ASP.NET Dependencies conditionally and use `#if` preprocessor directives.

```cs
"frameworks": {
  "net20": {
    "dependencies": {
      "NameOf.AspNetLegacyPackage": "1.2.3"
    }
  },
  "netstandard1.3": {
    "dependencies": {
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities" : "1.1.0"
    },
    "imports": "dnxcore50"
  }
}
```

I used `netstandard1.3` as that's the minimum for `Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities`, but depending on your other dependencies you may need to go higher or lower.

`NameOf.AspNetLegacyPackage` is the name of the package which contains the same functionality as `Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities` which you need, but which works on .NET Framework 2.0, if there is any. If not you have to remove it and write the replacement functions yourself.

Then in your code use

```cs
#if NETSTANDARD1_3
    // Code or APIs which is only available in netstandard1.3/net4.6 
    // this includes the Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtillities
#else
    // Use code or API which runs under .NET Framework 2.0
#endif
```

Alternatively, if you are going to give up the .NET Framework 2.0 support and go for 4.5.1, you can keep using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtillities` (see [NuGet page](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities/) for dependencies) it in both

```cs
"dependencies": {
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities" : "1.1.0"
},
"frameworks": {
  "net451": {
  },
  "netstandard1.3": {
    "imports": "dnxcore50"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by putting your code into a Shared project, then created a Class Library which targets .Net 2.0, and another Class Library project which targets NetStandard.  If there are things in 2.0 or Netstandard which aren't available in the other platform, you can use compiler directives to write compatible code for each.